# React App running in Heroku fails when retrieving large amounts of data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, heroku, mongodb-atlas

I have a react application (Node back end) running on Heroku (free option) connecting to a MongoDB running on Atlas (also free option).  When I connect the application from my local machine to the Atlas DB all is fine and data retrieved (all 108 K records) in about 10 seconds, smaller amounts (4-500 records) of data in much less time.  The same request from the application running on Heroku to the Atlas DB fails. The application running on Heroku can retrieve a small number of records (1-10) from the same collection of (108 K records), in less than a second.  As soon as I try to retrieve a couple of hundred records the system fails.  Below are the logs.  I included the section of the logs that show a successful retrieval of 1 record and then failing on the request for about 450 records.

I have three questions:

1. What is the cause of the issue?
2. Is there a work around in the free option of Heroku?
3. If there is no work around in the free option, what Heroku pay level will I need to get to and what steps will I need to take to get this working?  I will probably upgrade in the future but want to prove all is working before going in that direction.

Logs:

```
2021-06-14T17:26:17.488675+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/constructs/definitions/byMaxUpdateDate/5ed591a0570a1f29585b5cf6" host=protected-cliffs-99136.herokuapp.com request_id=3c01815a-23a3-46fa-ab75-4e36e76da739 fwd="73.119.93.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=321ms status=304 bytes=376 protocol=https
2021-06-14T17:26:17.573725+00:00 app[web.1]: ConstructDefinition.controller - listByCriteria - Start
2021-06-14T17:26:17.573762+00:00 app[web.1]: createQueryObj - iteration : 1  owner_id:  5ed591a0570a1f29585b5cf6
2021-06-14T17:26:17.573797+00:00 app[web.1]: createQueryObj - iteration : 2  myClass:  Academic
2021-06-14T17:26:17.573832+00:00 app[web.1]: createQueryObj - iteration : 3  category:  Vocabulary Expansion
2021-06-14T17:26:17.573861+00:00 app[web.1]: createQueryObj - iteration : 4  subject:  Vocabulary
2021-06-14T17:26:17.573896+00:00 app[web.1]: createQueryObj - iteration : 5  difficultyLevel:  6
2021-06-14T17:26:17.573923+00:00 app[web.1]: createQueryObj - iteration : 6  ageRange:  2
2021-06-14T17:26:17.573954+00:00 app[web.1]: createQueryObj - iteration : 7  topic:  zythum
2021-06-14T17:26:17.573999+00:00 app[web.1]: createQueryObject - queryString =  {"owner_id": "5ed591a0570a1f29585b5cf6","myClass": "Academic","category": "Vocabulary Expansion","subject": "Vocabulary","difficultyLevel": "6","ageRange": "2","topic": "zythum"}
2021-06-14T17:26:17.899908+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/constructs/definitions/byCriteria/5ed591a0570a1f29585b5cf6?owner_id=5ed591a0570a1f29585b5cf6&myClass=Academic&category=Vocabulary%20Expansion&subject=Vocabulary&difficultyLevel=6&ageRange=2&topic=zythum" host=protected-cliffs-99136.herokuapp.com request_id=5af21335-c10d-4ee6-981f-7232affcbfc2 fwd="73.119.93.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=360ms status=304 bytes=375 protocol=https


2021-06-14T17:26:36.487043+00:00 app[web.1]: ConstructDefinition.controller - listByCriteria - Start
2021-06-14T17:26:36.487603+00:00 app[web.1]: createQueryObj - iteration : 1  owner_id:  5ed591a0570a1f29585b5cf6
2021-06-14T17:26:36.487680+00:00 app[web.1]: createQueryObj - iteration : 2  myClass:  Academic
2021-06-14T17:26:36.487758+00:00 app[web.1]: createQueryObj - iteration : 3  difficultyLevel:  6
2021-06-14T17:26:36.487836+00:00 app[web.1]: createQueryObject - queryString =  {"owner_id": 

"5ed591a0570a1f29585b5cf6","myClass": "Academic","difficultyLevel": "6"}
    2021-06-14T17:27:04.964250+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/api/constructs/definitions/byCriteria/5ed591a0570a1f29585b5cf6?owner_id=5ed591a0570a1f29585b5cf6&myClass=Academic&false&false&difficultyLevel=6&false&false" host=protected-cliffs-99136.herokuapp.com request_id=79ec14d7-9e6c-41d7-9682-fd967bebbee4 fwd="73.119.93.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=28516ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
    2021-06-14T17:27:04.896082+00:00 app[web.1]:

2021-06-14T17:27:04.896093+00:00 app[web.1]: <--- Last few GCs --->
2021-06-14T17:27:04.896093+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-06-14T17:27:04.896095+00:00 app[web.1]: [21:0x5cc8230]   453328 ms: Mark-sweep 255.3 (258.1) -> 254.5 (258.1) MB, 146.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.133, current mu = 0.036) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
2021-06-14T17:27:04.896095+00:00 app[web.1]: [21:0x5cc8230]   453635 ms: Mark-sweep 255.4 (258.1) -> 254.6 (258.3) MB, 302.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.068, current mu = 0.016) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
2021-06-14T17:27:04.896096+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-06-14T17:27:04.896096+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-06-14T17:27:04.896096+00:00 app[web.1]: <--- JS stacktrace --->
2021-06-14T17:27:04.896096+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-06-14T17:27:04.896098+00:00 app[web.1]: ==== JS stack trace =========================================
2021-06-14T17:27:04.896098+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-06-14T17:27:04.896099+00:00 app[web.1]: 0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x145ce19]
2021-06-14T17:27:04.896100+00:00 app[web.1]: Security context: 0x05bfaa040921 <JSObject>
2021-06-14T17:27:04.896101+00:00 app[web.1]: 1: completeMany(aka completeMany) [0x199c8a762a21] [/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/query/completeMany.js:~21] [pc=0x1de09459122b](this=0x1096cc9004b9 <undefined>,0x0a6a9ed68769 <JSFunction model (sfi = 0x26feb614f221)>,0x23be33099751 <JSArray[100072]>,0x23be330a1591 <Object map = 0x2cc683e3d161>,0x23be330a1601 <Object map = 0x2cc683e3d161>,0x23be330a1...
2021-06-14T17:27:04.896101+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-06-14T17:27:04.896117+00:00 app[web.1]: FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
2021-06-14T17:27:04.896224+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-06-14T17:27:04.910524+00:00 app[web.1]: Writing Node.js report to file: report.20210614.172704.21.0.001.json
2021-06-14T17:27:04.910608+00:00 app[web.1]: Node.js report completed
2021-06-14T17:27:04.911501+00:00 app[web.1]: 1: 0xa9d570 node::Abort() [node]
2021-06-14T17:27:04.912203+00:00 app[web.1]: 2: 0xa9f832 node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
2021-06-14T17:27:04.913000+00:00 app[web.1]: 3: 0xc0772e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
2021-06-14T17:27:04.913707+00:00 app[web.1]: 4: 0xc07aa9 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
2021-06-14T17:27:04.914476+00:00 app[web.1]: 5: 0xdb5fb5  [node]
2021-06-14T17:27:04.915251+00:00 app[web.1]: 6: 0xdb6646 v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [node]
2021-06-14T17:27:04.916020+00:00 app[web.1]: 7: 0xdc4eb9 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
2021-06-14T17:27:04.916830+00:00 app[web.1]: 8: 0xdc5cf5 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
2021-06-14T17:27:04.917647+00:00 app[web.1]: 9: 0xdc87cc v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
2021-06-14T17:27:04.918404+00:00 app[web.1]: 10: 0xd8f3a4 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [node]
2021-06-14T17:27:04.919225+00:00 app[web.1]: 11: 0x10dc6ce v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
2021-06-14T17:27:04.920443+00:00 app[web.1]: 12: 0x145ce19  [node]
2021-06-14T17:27:04.964341+00:00 app[web.1]: Aborted
2021-06-14T17:27:04.968680+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-06-14T17:27:04.969190+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 134
2021-06-14T17:27:04.970722+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! teachlearngame@2.0.0 start: `NODE_ENV=production node ./dist/server.generated.js`
2021-06-14T17:27:04.970948+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 134
2021-06-14T17:27:04.971205+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-06-14T17:27:04.971416+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the teachlearngame@2.0.0 start script.
2021-06-14T17:27:04.971618+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-06-14T17:27:04.978470+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-06-14T17:27:04.978794+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-06-14T17:27:04.978986+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-06-14T17_27_04_972Z-debug.log
2021-06-14T17:27:05.035373+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 134
2021-06-14T17:27:05.174452+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-06-14T17:27:05.179240+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-06-14T17:27:13.491905+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-06-14T17:27:16.042157+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-06-14T17:27:16.042234+00:00 app[web.1]: > teachlearngame@2.0.0 start /app
2021-06-14T17:27:16.042240+00:00 app[web.1]: > NODE_ENV=production node ./dist/server.generated.js
2021-06-14T17:27:16.042245+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-06-14T17:27:19.878282+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-06-14T17:27:19.734472+00:00 app[web.1]: server - before call to initial load
2021-06-14T17:27:19.734929+00:00 app[web.1]: server - after call to initial load
2021-06-14T17:27:19.739564+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:21) ExperimentalWarning: Conditional exports is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
2021-06-14T17:27:19.740098+00:00 app[web.1]: Server started on port 28159.
```

Comment: From the errors, it looks like your server is running out of memory when trying to access more records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running out of heap memory in your node server. It might be because there's some statement that uses a lot of memory. You can try to find that or you can try to increase node memory [like this](https://blog.openreplay.com/javascript-heap-out-of-memory-error).

Comment: Thank you for your response.  As free option of heroku only provides up to 512 Meg I do not believe I can allocate additional RAM to the application.  My build was a bit large so I will work to reduce the footprint. I am sure that I will be able to find lots of suggestions on the Web but if you have any easy to apply methods to reduce the footprint of react apps applying SSR with a Node back end, it would be appreciated.